# Simulation terminated because derivative is not finite

Tags: matlab, initialization, simulink, derivative, singular

I encounter this error when I try to run my Simulink application.

> Derivative of state '1' in block 'proiect/Filtru/Integrator' at time 9.6046876340724416E-7 is not finite. The simulation will be stopped. There may be a singularity in the solution.  If not, try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error tolerances)

My Simulink app is this: [image]

and the block where I get the error looks like this: [image]

In the "Filtru" block, I set initial condition for the integrator block equal to `29.2`. If I set it to `0`, I do not get this error, but my initial condition has to be `29.2`.

My input is a step from `0` to `10`. I tried to reduce the step size, but nothing changed.

Comment: The "Filtru" virtual subsystem itself is fine. Your solver just exited here in this small algebraic loop. I suspect that filtru is part of a larger algebraic loop  (e.g. defining a differential equation like [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566018/solution-of-a-differential-equation-having-a-singularity-not-everywhere-defined] whichs solution is undefined) . To verify please replace Filtru with simple gain or transfer function. We need then to have a closer look to the other subsystems.